# C# JsonDocument.Parse() Auto casting

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I'm coding using C#.

When GET request, I get json format string like
`{ "code": 2312, "price": 98.322, ... }`

to parse, I use System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString) function.

I think they're type-casting internally.
But because of the floating-point error, I want JsonDocument.Parser to parse the string as it is.

You can also create a class and use JsonSerializer.Deserialize, but it is cumbersome because there are too many json properties.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] and add code demonstrating what is going wrong, and where you need help, as suggested by [ask]?  For instance, if you are having trouble parsing to `98.322` to a `double` because of the limitations of base-2 floating point math, possibly using `JsonElement.GetDecimal()` would resolve your problem, but I can't say for sure without knowing your exact problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Or you can use [`JsonElement.GetRawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getrawtext?view=net-8.0) to get the original JSON value backing a numeric element, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this behavior using [`JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-8.0) property which has the following values:

| Enum value | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals | 4 | The "NaN", "Infinity", and "-Infinity" String tokens can be read as floating-point constants, and the Single and Double values for these constants will be written as their corresponding JSON string representations. |
| AllowReadingFromString | 1 | Numbers can be read from String tokens. Does not prevent numbers from being read from Number token. |
| Strict | 0 | Numbers will only be read from Number tokens and will only be written as JSON numbers (without quotes). |
| WriteAsString | 2 | Numbers will be written as JSON strings (with quotes), not as JSON numbers. |

You will wan to use `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.Strict`. The default value for ASP.NET Core is `JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString`. From .NET 9 onwards you will be able to access the defaults this using the `JsonSerializerOptions.Web` singleton (See [MS Docs - Web defaults for `JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-8-0#web-defaults-for-jsonserializeroptions)).

You can configure this as a parameter to [`JsonSerailizer.Deserialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-string-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions))).

```cs
var jsonString = """
    { 
        "code": "2312", 
        "price": "98.322"
    }
    """;

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.Strict
})!;
Console.WriteLine($"Code: {result.Code}, Price: {result.Price}");


class MyObject {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set;}
}
```

If you were to change the properties to types `int` and `float`/ `double` you would get a `JsonException` when parsing.

Or, you can also configure this globally using [AddJsonOptions()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcjsonmvcbuilderextensions.addjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for all your controllers in ASP.NET Core:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.Strict);
```

However, once you make you object properties `string`s which you will have to do, you can omit to specify the `NumberHandling` since it then a conversion is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a little to understand your error here, but from what i gathered it seems you want to process the numbers as strings, this can be done by adding options to your json serialiser:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString // Handle floating-point numbers as strings
        };

        // Deserialize JSON to object
        var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString, options);
```